# Utilizing a remote microsoft access database in Android App

Tags: java, android, ms-access

I am writing an android application that takes in a string, read in by a bar code reader, and then when a particular button press occurs, it will send that string to the database and set their values either to "in stock" or "out of stock". I have not been able to find anything on this except for jackcesss, which does not seem to have any really good documentation on it. I cannot even get it to open the file with their example code. The code looks like this:

```
try {
    Database db = Database.open(new File("sdcard/download/Inventory-1.mdb"));

        db.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(CheckInActivity.this).setTitle("CRITICAL ERROR").setMessage("DATABASE FILE NOT FOUND. Please check your wireless connection").setPositiveButton("OK",null).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I run this code on my phone I get a force close (I run it on my phone each time to avoid emulator issues,also I am also try to make it work locally before I attempt to make it a remote file) However if I change the location of the file to something I know does not exist, it will catch it and pop up the dialog box that I specified. I tried this with and without closing the file, with throws and the try and catch, nothing seems to work. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

How do you know the database open was unsuccessful?  I'd put in an explicit indication to hit me over the head:

```
try {
      Database db = Database.open(new File("sdcard/download/Inventory-1.mdb"));
      new AlertDialog.Builder(CheckInActivity.this).setTitle("SUCCESS").setMessage("DATABASE WAS OPENED SUCCESSFULLY. ").setPositiveButton("OK",null).show();        db.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
         new AlertDialog.Builder(CheckInActivity.this).setTitle("CRITICAL ERROR").setMessage("DATABASE FILE NOT FOUND. Please check your wireless connection").setPositiveButton("OK",null).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: I have already tried this, and it forces close without giving me the the Success pop up.